# How can I determine if there is a space in a GET or POST key?

Tags: php

In PHP if I have the following script:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

How can I differentiate the following requests:

```
GET /foo?hello%20dude=cool
GET /foo?hello_dude=cool
```

they both print:

```
array(1) { ["hello_dude"]=> string(4) "cool" }
```

since key names are not allowed to have spaces? Do I have to manually parse the POST data as well as the GET data or is there an easier way?

Comment: Yes, PHP automatically replaces spaces or periods in parameter names with an underscore. For GET, you could inspect the query string; for POST you will have to read the raw POST data. // But why does this actually matter for your script?

Comment: @CBroe it makes a difference because it is changing the OAuth signature

Comment: Who’s checking the OAuth signature – are you the OAuth provider in this case, or a user of it? If you are the provider here, then I’d simply let it fail with an invalid signature in such cases – and tell people who are using your service that they have to avoid such ambiguous parameter names …

Comment: @CBroe There's nothing ambiguous about a key in the query string that has a space in it.

Comment: I agree with @Brad. Those are different parameters and should be treated differently.  Of course, this is PHP, which also brought us the "multivalued parameters have to have [] in the name" nonsense...

Comment: @MarkReed Other frameworks use that notation as well (Rails comes to mind) and yes, I have no idea why when simply repeating the key worked well for the rest of the world.

Comment: @Brad: They _are_ ambiguous under these circumstances, _because_ PHP has this (defined) behavior. I don’t say that you have to _like_, that is just how it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are going to have to bypass PHP's automatic parsing of the query string and do it yourself.

You can get the full request URI by checking `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`.  From there, you can split on the first question mark `?`, then split on ampersand `&`, then split each by `=`.  There may also be a handy regex solution.